# override classes variable, or at least variable type in objective-c / cocoa

Tags: overriding, nscoding

My dilemma is as follows:

I have a custom subclass of UIImage (I've added some serialization methods i.e. initWithCoder, encodeWithCoder), and I would like to apply my custom subclass as a variable to a UIImageView, or at least a subclass of UIImageView.

As you are aware, UIImageView has a variable called "image", that is of type UIImage.  I'd like to override this variable with my subclass.

My goal is to have a UIimageView that will respond to archivedDataWithRootObject without crashing with the encodeWithCoder message is sent to the variable image.  If there is a smarter way to get there, I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you!

[edit] I think one possible route is through some type of casting...However:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
MLImage *mlImage = [[MLImage alloc] init];
mlIamge = (MLImage*)image;
```

When I mouse-over mlImage after the second line executes, I can see that it is of type MLImage.  However, even with the cast, after the third line executes mlImage becomes a UIImage.  What do I need to do to change the type of image to MLImage?
[/edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with your terminology. It's not possible to *override* a property—the `UIImageView` will still have its own `image` property, it won't be replaced. You're trying to override the *accessors* (`-image` and `-setImage:`).

And you're right, casting is a better route. But your example has a problem: that cast is illegal. When you do `[[UIImage alloc] init]`, you're creating an object of type `UIImage`. Nothing is going to change that, including your cast. Casting is a way of telling the compiler (in your case) "I know you think that this `UIImage*` is, well, a `UIImage`, but it's really a `MLImage`." In this case, that's a lie, since it really is a `UIImage`—you allocated it right there.

What you *can* do, though, is stick an actual `MLImage` into the `image` property of a `UIImageView`. For example:

```
MLImage *myImage = [[MLImage alloc] init];
myView.image = myImage;
```

And then somewhere else:

```
MLImage *myImage = (MLImage *)(myView.image);
```

And you'll get back your custom image object. But it has to have been an `MLImage` in the first place.